# Richfaces + Spring DataTable DataScroler problem

Tags: spring, jsf, datatable, richfaces

I try to use Richfaces DataTable with DataTableModel to have server side paging and sorting.

My tebaleModel is a spring bean with scope "request" and " proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS".

On the page is a keepAlive tag for tebaleModel bean.

When I click next the bean is initialized but it should be restored.

Can anybody help. I can provide the code if my question is not clear.

---

**Update**:

1. My bean impelements Serializable, because SerializableDataModel which I extend implements Serializable
2. is within a form

In another managedBean I have type if bean proxy and keepAlive works just fine. I don't use this for DataTableModel becasue it doesnt't work with this pattern.

Maybe if you see the code you notice what I done wrong.

Here is my code

ManagedBean:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class UserTableDataModel extends SerializableDataModel implements Modifiable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4188575485838003516L;
    @Autowired
    private UserManager userManager;
    private Long currentPk;
    private Map<Long, User> wrappedData;
    private List<Long> wrappedKeys;
    private int pageSize;
    private int pageNo;
    private int pages;
    private SortInfo sortInfo;
    private List<SelectItem> pagesList;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        wrappedKeys = null;
        wrappedData = new HashMap<Long, User>();
        pageSize = 1;
        pageNo = 1;
        pages = userManager.getUserCount() / pageSize;
        pagesList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        for (int i = 1; i < pages + 1; i++) {
            pagesList.add(new SelectItem(i));
        }
    }
    @PreDestroy
    public void clen(){
        System.out.println("ddd");
    }

    /**
     * Getter for pagesList.
     * 
     * @return the pagesList
     */
    public List<SelectItem> getPagesList() {
        return pagesList;
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey() {
        return this.currentPk;
    }

    @Override
    public void setRowKey(Object key) {
        this.currentPk = (Long) key;

    }

    @Override
    public void walk(FacesContext context, DataVisitor visitor, Range range, Object argument) throws IOException {
        int firstRow = ((SequenceRange) range).getFirstRow();
        int numberOfRows = ((SequenceRange) range).getRows();
        int pageNumber = firstRow / pageSize;
        setPageNo(pageNumber + 1);
        wrappedKeys = new ArrayList<Long>();
        for (User item : userManager.getUsers(new PresentationInfo(new PageInfo(pageSize, pageNumber), sortInfo))) {
            wrappedKeys.add(item.getId());
            wrappedData.put(item.getId(), item);
            visitor.process(context, item.getId(), argument);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return userManager.getUserCount();
    }

    @Override
    public User getRowData() {
        if (currentPk == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            User ret = wrappedData.get(currentPk);
            if (ret == null) {
                try {
                    ret = userManager.getUser(currentPk);
                } catch (UserManagerBusinessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ValidationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                wrappedData.put(currentPk, ret);
                return ret;
            } else {
                return ret;
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getRowIndex() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getWrappedData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRowAvailable() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setRowIndex(int rowIndex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setWrappedData(Object data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public SerializableDataModel getSerializableModel(Range range) {
        SerializableDataModel model = null;
        if (wrappedKeys != null) {
            model = this;
        }
        return model;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for pageSize.
     * 
     * @return the pageSize
     */
    public int getPageSize() {
        return pageSize;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for pageSize.
     * 
     * @param pageSize the pageSize to set
     */
    public void setPageSize(int pageSize) {
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for pageNo.
     * 
     * @return the pageNo
     */
    public int getPageNo() {
        return pageNo;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for pageNo.
     * 
     * @param pageNo the pageNo to set
     */
    public void setPageNo(int pageNo) {
        this.pageNo = pageNo;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for pages.
     * 
     * @return the pages
     */
    public int getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    @Override
    public void modify(List<FilterField> filterFields, List<SortField2> sortFields) {
        if (sortFields != null && !sortFields.isEmpty()) {
            sortInfo = new SortInfo();
            for (SortField2 sf : sortFields) {
                Ordering order = sf.getOrdering();
                String exp = sf.getExpression().getExpressionString();
                String fieldName = exp.substring(exp.indexOf('.') + 1, exp.indexOf('}'));
                if (Ordering.ASCENDING.equals(order)) {
                    sortInfo.addSortFieldAscending(fieldName);
                } else {
                    sortInfo.addSortFieldDescending(fieldName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

web page userTable.xhtml:

```
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
        xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
        template="/templates/mainTemplate.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="bean" value="${userTableDataModel}" />
        <ui:define name="mainPage">
            <h:form id="${commonBean.mainFormName}">
                <a4j:keepAlive beanName="userTableDataModel" />
                <h:panelGrid columns="1" columnClasses="top , top">
                    <rich:dataTable id="table" value="#{bean}" var="user" width="580px"
                        rows="#{bean.pageSize}" sortMode="multi" selectionMode="single">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="${userMsg.users}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <rich:column sortable="true" label="${userMsg.firstName}"
                            sortBy="#{user.firstName}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="${userMsg.firstName}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{user.firstName}" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column label="${userMsg.lastName}" sortable="true"
                            sortBy="#{user.lastName}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="${userMsg.lastName}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{user.lastName}" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column sortable="true" sortBy="#{user.login}"
                            label="${userMsg.login}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="${userMsg.login}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{user.login}" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="footer">
                            <rich:datascroller maxPages="#{bean.pages}" fastControls="hide"
                                page="#{bean.pageNo}" pagesVar="pages" id="ds">
                                <f:facet name="first">
                                    <h:outputText value="First" styleClass="scrollerCell" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="first_disabled">
                                    <h:outputText value="First" styleClass="scrollerCell" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="last">
                                    <h:outputText value="Last" styleClass="scrollerCell" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="last_disabled">
                                    <h:outputText value="Last" styleClass="scrollerCell" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="previous">
                                    <h:outputText value="Previous" styleClass="scrollerCell" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="previous_disabled">
                                    <h:outputText value="Previous" styleClass="scrollerCell" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="next">
                                    <h:outputText value="Next" styleClass="scrollerCell" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="next_disabled">
                                    <h:outputText value="Next" styleClass="scrollerCell" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="pages">
                                    <h:panelGroup>
                                        <h:outputText value="Page " />
                                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.pageNo}"
                                            onchange="#{rich:component('ds')}.switchToPage(this.value)">
                                            <f:selectItems value="#{bean.pagesList}" />
                                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                                        <h:outputText value=" of #{pages}" />
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                </f:facet>
                            </rich:datascroller>
                        </f:facet>

                    </rich:dataTable>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work around is to do the interface which is implemented by the model and provided a method to return model itselft. Then everything is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your bean has to implement `Serializable`
2. the `<a4j:keepAlive>` should be within a form
3. Try adding `<f:view>` around
4. As a sidenote, you'd better make all your spring dependencies (the classes injected into the managed bean) `transient`, and then restore them from the spring context in `readResolve`. Serializing the whole hierarchy of injected beans, potentially with proxies might be cumbersome.

Comment: As I sad before:
p1 - SerializableDataModel implements Serializable and I extend it so my class implements Serializable to
p2 - it is in form
p3 - doesn't change any thing
p4 - no need

I thing the problem is with bean proxy mode  proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS.
But I need this type for table model. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Tried removing the proxy mode?

Comment: yes. but then is another problem, because exprexion "bean.user" is not resolved on class Proxy49. 
Thats why I use proxy mode target class to have the orginal class.

I use keep alive and bean without proxy mode for another web page anf it's working fine.

But for this page I need with proxy mode = taget_class. Have you tried to do such thing?

Comment: I have used a lot spring+jsf, with proxied controllers (by myfaces orchestra) with no troubles, and keepAlive as well, so I'm trying to see something that's wrong, but apart from the above points, I cant't

Comment: the problem is with tablemodel. For "normla" beans it's ok. But table model need to exdent SerializableTableModel or ExtendedTableModel. I use it for server side sorting and paging. When there is proxy richfaces mechanizm doesn't see that my class is of type SerializableTableModel or ExtendedTableModel. 
Thats why I use proxy mode target class. 
But with this proxy mode keepAlive doesn't work. The bean (tableModel) is initialized for all requests.

Comment: I don't get why such bean is not keept alive! :(